# How can I handle uniqueness in this situation?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I have a table like this:

```
create table my_table
(
type1 varchar2(10 char),
type2 varchar2(10 char) 
);
```

I want to uniqueness like this;

1. if **type1** column has 'GENERIC' value then just **type2** column must be unique for the table. for example;

   - type1 column has 'GENERIC' value and type2 column has 'value_x' then there must not any type2 column value that equals to 'value_x'.
2. But other uniqueness is looking for both column. I mean it should be unique by type1 and type2  columns.(of course first rule is constant)

I try to make it with trigger;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE trigger my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
       lvn_count NUMBER :=0;
       lvn_count2 NUMBER :=0;
       errormessage clob;
       MUST_ACCUR_ONE EXCEPTION;
    --   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; --without this it gives mutating error but I cant use this because it will conflict on simultaneous connections
BEGIN

      IF :NEW.type1 = 'GENERIC' THEN

       SELECT count(1) INTO lvn_count FROM my_table
       WHERE type2= :NEW.type2;
      
      ELSE 
      
       SELECT count(1) INTO lvn_count2 FROM my_table
       WHERE type1= :NEW.type1 and type2= :NEW.type2;
 
      END IF;     
 

       IF (lvn_count >= 1 or lvn_count2 >= 1) THEN
             RAISE MUST_ACCUR_ONE; 
       END IF;

END;
```

But it gives **mutating** error without **pragma** . I do not want to use it due to conflict on simultaneous connections. (error because I use same table on trigger)

I try to make it with unique index but I cant manage.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_table_unique_ix 
ON my_table (case when type1= 'GENERIC' then 'some_logic_here' else type1 end, type2);  -- I know it does not make sense but maybe there is something different that I can use in here.
```

Examples;

```
**Example 1**

insert into my_table (type1,type2) values ('a','b'); -- its ok no problem

insert into my_table (type1,type2) values ('a','c'); -- its ok no problem

insert into my_table (type1,type2) values ('c','b'); -- its ok no problem

insert into my_table (type1,type2) values ('GENERIC','b'); -- it should be error because b is exist before (i look just second column because first column value is 'GENERIC')


EXAMPLE 2:

insert into my_table (type1,type2) values ('GENERIC','b'); -- its ok no problem

insert into my_table (type1,type2) values ('a','c'); -- its ok no problem

insert into my_table (type1,type2) values ('d','c'); -- its ok no problem

insert into my_table (type1,type2) values ('d','b'); -- it should be error because second column can not be same as the second column value that first column value is 'GENERIC'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not really straightforward in Oracle. One possible (although somewhat cumbersome) approach is to use a combination of

- an additional materialized view with `refresh (on commit)`
- a windowing function to compute the number of distinct values per group
- a windowing function to compute the number of GENERIC rows per group
- a check constraint to ensure that either we have only one DISTINCT value or we don't have GENERIC in the same group

This should work:

```
create materialized view mv_my_table 
refresh on commit
as
select 
 type1,
 type2,
 count(distinct type1) over (partition by type2) as distinct_type1_cnt,
 count(case when type1 = 'GENERIC' then 1 else null end) 
     over (partition by type2) as generic_cnt
from my_table;

alter table mv_my_table add constraint chk_type1 
  CHECK (distinct_Type1_cnt = 1 or generic_cnt = 0);
```

Now, INSERTing a duplicate won't fail immediately, but the subsequent COMMIT will fail because it triggers the materialized view refresh, and that will cause the check constraint to fire.

**Disadvantages**

- duplicate INSERTs won't fail immediately (making debugging more painful)
- depending on the size of your table, the MView refresh might slow down COMMITs considerably

**Links**

For a more detailed discussion of this approach, see [AskTom on cross-row constraints](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=best-way-to-enforce-cross-row-constraints)

Comment: This logic can be put in an after statement trigger too or am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie  The trigger approach doesn't work correctly in a multi-session scenario - see my comment on your answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    type1 VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
    type2 VARCHAR2(10 CHAR),
    type1_unique VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( NULLIF(type1, 'GENERIC') ) VIRTUAL
);

ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD (CONSTRAINT my_table_unique_ix UNIQUE (type1_unique, type2) USING INDEX)
```

Or an index like this should also work:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_table_unique_ix ON MY_TABLE (NULLIF(type1, 'GENERIC'), type2);
```

Or doing it in your style (you only missed the `END`):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_table_unique_ix ON my_table (case when type1= 'GENERIC' then null else type1 end, type2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesnt important null control"?

Comment: I just updated my question could you have a look of it, null control is not the main problem. I cant do the uniqueness which i want

Comment: None of the three suggestions work correctly (because unique indices ignore NULL values).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, the logic in the answer from @Frank Schmitt can also be implemented using a statement level trigger. It is a lot simpler to implement and does not have the disadvantages that Frank mentions.

```
create or replace TRIGGER my_table_t
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE 
    ON my_table
DECLARE
  l_dummy NUMBER;
  MUST_ACCUR_ONE EXCEPTION;  
BEGIN
  WITH constraint_violated AS
  (
  select 
   type1,
   type2,
   count(distinct type1) over (partition by type2) as distinct_type1_cnt,
   count(case when type1 = 'GENERIC' then 1 else null end) 
       over (partition by type2) as generic_cnt
  from my_table
  )
  SELECT 1 INTO l_dummy 
    FROM constraint_violated
   WHERE NOT (distinct_type1_cnt = 1 or generic_cnt = 0) FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
  RAISE MUST_ACCUR_ONE; 
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  NULL;
END;
/
```

Comment: The problem with triggers is that they're not really reliable in a concurrent scenario. This can be reproduced by:
- creating the table and trigger
- session A: perform the first three INSERTs from the OP's example (DO NOT COMMIT YET)
- session B: perform the fourth INSERT from the OP's example (the GENERIC / b one). This should fail, but it doesn't, since the trigger doesn't "see" the uncommited INSERTs from session A
- session B: commit
- session A: commit

Et voilà, you now have rows with a/b and GENERIC/b in your table.

Comment: Ah thanks - I missed that.